# Current user data after login in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on an auth system in React-Redux.After successfull login, I want to keep the current data.I can't do it right tho.

ACTIONS CODE:

```
// ** LOGIN USER **
export const login = ({ email, password }) => (dispatch) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  axios
    .post('/login', body, getHeaders())
    .then(console.log(body))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });

      history.push('/');
    })
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
      });
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.message, err.id, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });
    });
};
```

How can I store the user data in USER_LOADED type?It works only before the first reload.

REDUCERS CODE:

```
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  isLoading: false,
  user: null,
  profileInitialized: false,
  profileData: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // USER AUTHENTICATION
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
       +++
```

I should add that JWT stays after reload so user is connected but with no username shown for example.

[Right after the login redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR3tD.png)

[After Reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJi2G.png)

I know the code

```
 .then(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
      });
    })
```

is wrong but I don't know how to make it work

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the redux-thunk middleware!
const middleware = [thunk]; etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can you please explain `After successfull login, I want to keep the current data.I can't do it right tho.`?

Comment: When I login I get the user data as response (id,email,username, gender). I want to keep this data for the whole time the user is logged in.
For example I'm using the username at the navbar.
I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: Are you trying to persist data in browser and pull it back when USER_LOADED is triggered? So you will still have the data after refreshing the page in a browser?

Comment: Exactly Andrew.After the login, I want to have the data stored so I can use it until user logs out.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully it makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the user data is from `POST /login`. If this is the case, I think you need to remove `.then(console.log(body))` first, since it doesn't return the response to the next `.then` function. Also, you need to return the user data down the promise chain. I hope that helps.

```
axios
  .post('/login', body, getHeaders()) 
  .then((res) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data,
   });

   history.push('/');

   return res.data; // pass the user data down to the promise chain
}).then((user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: USER_LOADED,
    payload: user
   });
})
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comment in the original question. The question is about persisting data in browser and pull it back when USER_LOADED is triggered.

I think you can use the local storage to store the user information just like how you do it with `token` for the initialState. So it will always try to use saved user info.

After the POST call, you can add the user info from the payload into the local storage. So it will still be available after page refresh.

```
axios
  .post('/login', body, getHeaders()) 
  .then((res) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data,
   });

   // I assume user data is part of the `POST /login` payload 
   localStorage.setItem('user', res.data.user)

   history.push('/');

   return res.data; // pass the user data down to the promise chain
})
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: It still doesn't work.After refresh _user_ is null.Works only the first time when LOGIN_SUCCESS action type is called.